# Пытаюсь создать текстовый файл с помощью WinApi C++ в папке C:\\User\\%username%\\text.txt, но что-то не выходит, помогите

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система, c++17

[image: Пример (говно-кода)кода]

```
class User
{
public:
char username[1024];
DWORD username_len = 1024;
};
User user;
GetUserNameA(user.username, &user.username_len);

LPCTSTR asd = ("C:\\Users\\" + std::string(user.username) + "\\text.txt");

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile
    (asd,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
```

Comment: И что, *это* компилируется?! ни за что не поверю... А вообще, см. в сторону С-строк и функций типа `strcat`...

Comment: Нет не компилирует

Comment: Ну, я намек сделал... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `asd` имеет тип `string`:

```
string asd = "C:\\Users\\" + std::string(user.username) + "\\text.txt";

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile
    (asd.c_str(),
```

Comment: #include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class User
{
public:
 char username[1024];
 DWORD username_len = 1024;
};

void main()
{
 User user;
 GetUserNameA(user.username, &user.username_len);

 string asd = "C:\\Users\\" + std::string(user.username) + "\\text.txt";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile
    (asd.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
}

Comment: я написал данным образом, но где (asd.c_str(), (пишет const char* не совместим с параметром типа LPCWSTR)

Comment: Решил проблему, зашел в свойства проекта и поставил в Дополнительно -> Набор символов -> Использовать многобайтовую кодировку